# Calculating the area under an n-dimensional density given its cumulative density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Suppose we have an n-dimensional probability density function $f(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ and have access to its cumulative density function $F(\cdot )$.

We want to calculate the area under the density given by:
$A_{(a_1, b_1, \dots, a_n, b_n)}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = f(x_1 - a_1 < X_1 \le x_1 + b_1, \ \dots \ , x_n - a_1 < X_n \le x_n + b_1)$

An example: If $a_i = b_i = 0.50 \ \forall \ i = \{1,\dots,n\}$ then the area is an n-dimensional unit cube centered around $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Is there are a general formula for how we can calculate $A(\cdot)$ / Are my thoughts correct (see below)?

**My thoughts:**

I had the idea that we can use the CDF and Cuts to calculate $A(\cdot)$. We use the CDF to calculate an overestimation of the area; then, additional CDF calls to cut away the overestimation. The following are my results for 1D, 2D and 3D. I can't guarantee the accuracy of these results; I did them thinking of a visual representation of the problem:

- **1D:**

$\begin{align}
A_{(a_1, b_1)}(x_1) & = f(x_1 - a_1 < X_1 \le x_1 + b_1) \\ & = F(x_1 + b_1) - F(x_1 - a_1)
\end{align}$

- **2D:**

$\begin{align}
A_{(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2)}(x_1, x_2) & = f(x_1 - a_1 < X_1 \le x_1 + b_1, x_2 - a_2 < X_2 \le x_2 + b_2) \\ & = F(x_1 + b_1, x_2 + b_2) - F(x_1 + b_1, x_2 - a_2) - F(x_1 - a_1, x_2 + b_2) + F(x_1 - a_1, x_2 - a_2)
\end{align}$

- **3D:**

$\begin{align}
A_{(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, a_3, b_3)}(x_1, x_2, x_3) 
& = f(x_1 - a_1 < X_1 \le x_1 + b_1, x_2 - a_2 < X_2 \le x_2 + b_2, x_3 - a_3 < X_3 \le x_3 + b_3) \\ 
& = F(x_1 + b_1, \ x_2 + b_2, \ x_3 + b_3) \\
& - F(x_1 - a_1, \ x_2 + b_2, \ x_3 + b_3) \\
& - F(x_1 + b_1, \ x_2 - a_2, \ x_3 + b_3) \\
& - F(x_1 + b_1, \ x_2 + b_2, \ x_3 - a_3) \\
& + F(x_1 - a_1, \ x_2 - a_2, \ x_3 + b_3) \\
& + F(x_1 - a_1, \ x_2 + b_2, \ x_3 - a_3) \\
& + F(x_1 + b_1, \ x_2 - a_2, \ x_3 - a_3) \\
& - F(x_1 - a_1, \ x_2 - a_2, \ x_3 - a_3)
\end{align}$

From these results, it looks like there is a general formula to the problem. It seems to be:

$A_{(a_1, b_1, \dots, a_n, b_n)}(x_1, \dots, x_n)  = \prod_{I \in T} \Big ( \text{Sign} (\prod_{i=1}^{N}(I)) \cdot F(x_1 + I_1, \ \dots \ , c_n + I_n )\Big )$

where $I_i \in \{-a_i, +b_i\}$ and $T$ is the set of all possible combinatorical combination of $I=(I_1, \dots, I_n)$

In short, we have to sum all possible terms of the CDF wrt adding/substracting $\{a_i, b_i\}$. The sign before the CDF-term in the sum is negative if we change an odd number of $b_i$'s to $a_i$'s and stays positive if we change an even number of $b_i$'s to $a_i$'s.

**My question:** Is this true? If so, how can we prove something like this for $n > 3$?